# How to change dependency property behavior in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF user control which contains a `TextBox` and some buttons. Now I want to change the way in which the `VerticalContentAlignment` property of the user control is handled in order to change only the vertical content alignment of the contained text box and not of the user control itself. So how can I override the `VerticalContentAlignment` dependency property of the user control in order to achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: Write a ControlTemplate for the UserControl that simply ignores the VerticalContentAlignment property. Then bind the TextBox's VerticalAlignment (or whatever) to the VerticalContentAlignment property of the UserControl, e.g. by a RelativeSource Binding.

Comment: Hmm, could you show me small example. Not sure if I understand your suggestion correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a ControlTemplate for the UserControl that simply ignores the VerticalContentAlignment property. Then bind the TextBox's VerticalAlignment to the VerticalContentAlignment property of the UserControl, e.g. by a RelativeSource Binding.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <ContentPresenter
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>

    <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <TextBlock
            Text="Hello"
            VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Test case:

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyUserControl
        Height="100" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hmm it seems to work, but to be honest I do not really understand why. Especially this line:

<ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />

Shouldn't this end up in an endless loop?

Comment: That line isn't there. There's only the HorizontalAlignment property of the **Content**Presenter bound to the Horizontal**Content**Alignment property of the UserControl, and that's the point. No Binding of the ContentPresenter's VerticalAlignment.

Comment: OK, this was my fault. But then this approach means that all other properties (besides the HorizontalContentAlignment) like Background etc. do also no longer work.

Comment: It's just a simple example. If the ControlTemplate is supposed to contain more elements, which bind to other properties of the UserControl (by other TemplateBindings), just add them. E.g. a Border that binds to Background, BorderBrush and BorderThickness.